# SharePoint 2013 Pages library "Most popular items" returning zero count (except homepage)

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I'm new to SharePoint and have been unable to find an answer to this problem.

When selecting "Most Popular Items" on the Pages library the homepage is returning a count for "Recent" and "Ever", but all other pages are returning a zero count. The homepage has a different content type and page layout from the other pages.

Videos library is returning zero count for all videos.

Documents library is recording as expected.

I'm not sure is this is related but sorting by Recent/Ever is broken on all libraries.

Comment: Is this issue fixed.? can you tell the steps to fix. I am facing the similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

Can you create a new site collection and check whether this issue can be reproduced? 
Couple of things you can perform:

Whats the ULS logs saying? and also have a look at EventViewer as well.

Have you configured search on this Farm?

Whats the site template you have chosen while creating site?

Enable/Disable few features like publishing etc

Whats the access rights you are having on this site? Add yourself as site collec. admin and see whether this issue persists.

let us know the results of the above

Comment: We've inherited this site so I'll need to investigate further. It might take a while to action your suggestions.